# How is it possible to access fields of a class in its base class?

Tags: python, mongodb, reflection

I have some classes to access my collections in mongoDB. I've created a lot of methods for each class. Now I want to know if there is any way to implement these methods once and then my mongoDB classes only contains fields? look at this example:

```
#mongoBase.py
class MongoBase():
    def insert()
        pass
    def update()
        pass

#user.py
class User(MongoBase):
# Here should be only fields declaration and when I call .insert(), the fields should be inserted.
```

I did it in Java using java reflection. but I can't find something like that in python.

Comment: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/ check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can achieve what you're trying to do by simply referring to `self` in the parent class.

Here's the code I used:

```
class MongoBase(object):
    def insert(self, field, value):
        setattr(self, field, value)
    def update(self, field, value):
        setattr(self, field, value)

class User(MongoBase):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

And here's how it works:

```
>>> user = User('Bob')
>>> user.name
'Bob'
>>> user.update('name', 'Rob')
>>> user.name
'Rob'
>>> user.insert('age', 12)
>>> user.age
12
```